# How to loop through a JSON object?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I want to loop through an arbitrary JSON object in Python and get all values. I do not know what the JSON object looks like. I just want to loop through all elements. So also through the child objects and lists. I have now taken an arbitrary JSON object from the Internet to test. But it could also be any other JSON object. Currently I try it like this:

```
def printJSONVals(json_object): 
    it = iter(json_object)
    n = json_object[next(it)]
    while n is not None:
        print n
        n = json_object[next(it)]

json_obj = json.loads('{ "city" : "AGAWAM", "loc" : [ -72.622739, 42.070206 ], "pop" : 15338, "state" : "MA", "_id" : "01001"}')

printJSONVals(json_obj)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, because I get the list `"loc"` back as a list and not the individual values. Is there a way to loop through a JSON object regardless of the depth of the nesting and always store the value of the individual keys in the variable `n`?

As a result, I want the variable `n` to always contain the values of the keys. Regardless of the depth of the nesting of the object. So I expect this output here:

```
AGAWAM
-72.622739
42.070206
15338
MA
01001
```

I would like to write these later in a two-dimensional array. But this is not important. It is enough if I manage to output the values independent of the nesting.

I use Python version 2.7.17

Thank you

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: I want to create a two-dimensional array, which always contains the following data: ("key", "parent", "val")

Comment: The OP wants to print the values of a json objet considering `list` and `dict` are collections… He needs a recursive function…

Comment: What is OP standig for?

Comment: What do you mean by “parent”?

Comment: I would like to point out that as specified [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp) that for JSON: Data is in name/value pairs, Data is separated by commas, Curly braces hold objects, Square brackets hold arrays. And as Laurent says you need to look into a recursive function with this in mind.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253162/what-is-an-op-when-referring-to-stack-exchange

Comment: I’m pretty sure this question is a duplicate.

Comment: I searched for it... But couldn`t find a similar question

Comment: Here [this](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-loop-through-a-JSON-file-with-multiple-keys-sub-keys-in-Python) and [this](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/pythonCkJsonObjectRef.html) might help.

Comment: `json_obj` is not a "JSON object". It's a `dict`. JSON stopped being relevant as soon as `json.loads` returned.

Comment: _I am using Python 2.7_ Why is that? Have you done any research? This is a very common topic.

Comment: Ali: You're the OP (original poster—the person asking the question). Please [edit] your question and show what output you would expect from the same input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use  `dict` keys to calculate the path of ancestors.

```py
import json


def print_json(obj, parent=None):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for child in obj:
            for path, item in print_json(child, parent):
                yield path, item
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key, child in obj.iteritems():  # items() in Python3
            child_path = [key] if parent is None else parent + [key]
            for path, item in print_json(child, child_path):
                yield path, item
    else:
        yield parent, obj
```

With you example, you have:

```py
json_obj = json.loads(
    '{ "city" : "AGAWAM", "loc" : [ -72.622739, 42.070206 ], "pop" : 15338, "state" : "MA", "_id" : "01001"}'
)

for path, item in print_json(json_obj):
    print(path, ":", item)
```

The result:

```py
['city'] : AGAWAM
['loc'] : -72.622739
['loc'] : 42.070206
['pop'] : 15338
['state'] : MA
['_id'] : 01001
```

Another example:

```py
json_obj = json.loads(
    '{ "city" : "AGAWAM", "loc" : { "type": "int", "value": 16}}'
)
```

You get:

```py
['city'] : AGAWAM
['loc', 'type'] : int
['loc', 'value'] : 16
```